# Oracle SQL Timestamp format

Tags: sql, oracle, timestamp, format

I have a timestamp field in the database to which i need to format as:

**2003-08-09T05:48:37+05:30**

How to do this formatting?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSTIMESTAMP, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SSTZH:TZM') FROM DUAL
```